# Creating unique Index for table in hibernate with one column being a foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate

well I am not that advanced in hibernate and I tried to search a lot, found lots of similar questions but none really applying my case. I have a table TABLE1 which has an index "id" and another table which has as index (TABLE1_ID and NUMBER). Only TABLE1_ID is a foreign key while number doesn't reference anything specific

TABLE 1 has the following hibernate mapping

```
 <class name="com.test.basic.BASICTABLE1"
    entity-name="com.test.TABLE1" table="TABLE1"
    dynamic-update="true" optimistic-lock="version">
    <id name="id" type="long">
        <column name="id" />
        <generator class="native">
            <param name="sequence">${table1_id.generator.sequence}</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <version name="versionNumber" column="verno" generated="always"
        access="field" />
    <property name="column1" column="column1" type="string" length="19"
        not-null="true" access="field" />
 </class>
```

I am not sure what should be the mapping for the other table. I did it the following way

```
  <class name="com.test.basic.BASICTABLE2"
    entity-name="com.test.TABLE2" table="table2"
    dynamic-update="true" optimistic-lock="version">

    <composite-id name="id" class="com.test.basic.TABLE1TABLE2Id" >
      <key-property name="TABLE1_ID" column="TABLE1_ID" type="long" />
      <key-property name="NUMBER" column="NUMBER" type="short"/>
    </composite-id>
 </class>
```

Please note that I created the class TABLE1TABLE2Id after I read somewhere that there should be some intermediate mapping.

I'm sure there's something wrong with TABLE2 mapping (I am not so advanced with hibernate) but when trying to install the app, I am getting the following error

```
 Foreign key (TABLE1 [id]) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (TABLE2 [TABLE1_ID, NUMBER])
```

I appreciate anybody's help thanks :)

Comment: What version of hibernate do you use?

Comment: The version of hibernate is 3.3.1, thanks :)

Comment: Did you hide some information for us such as many-to-one mapping?

Comment: Well no, though I tried it as <key-many-to-one> in the composite-id still had the same error. Table 1 contains other many to one mappings but they're all working fine

Answer (score 0):

[Identity copy (foreign generator)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-declaration-id)

> Finally, you can ask Hibernate to copy the identifier from another
>   associated entity. In the Hibernate jargon, it is known as a foreign
>   generator but the JPA mapping reads better and is encouraged.

The primary key from one entity might be as foreign key be primary key for another table.

```
@Entity
class MedicalHistory implements Serializable {
  @Id Integer id;

  @MapsId @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id")
  Person patient;
}

@Entity
class Person {
  @Id @GeneratedValue Integer id;
}
```